# Return last row from a Table mysql Error

Tags: mysql, row, final

Trying to get last row from a database, but when the table is new and no row is entered, it return error.

```
$lastrow="select ID from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"; 
$lastrow=mysql_query($lastrow);
echo $lastrow;
$lastrow=mysql_result($lastrow,0) + 1;
```

How to fix that so that even if the table is new it return last row (I mean first row in this case)

Comment: So what do you want to be returned when the table is empty?

Comment: First row of table I can insert, id 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to check if the `ID` is `null`, then return `0` (or something else whatever you want):

```
select COALESCE(MAX(uid), 0) from users
```

You can simply use `MAX` to get the last inserted `ID`, if it will be null the query will return `0` instead.

But I would suggest you to use `Auto Increment` on table's ID. Because you don't know if someone else also has that `lastID + 1` value as ID.

Comment: $empty ="select COALESCE(ID, 0) from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1";  $queryempt=mysql_query($empty);

Comment: How to put that in condition does $queryempty return 0 ? (if empty)

Comment: Yes you did it fine, the query I provided will return `0` if there will be no row in table.

Comment: $empty ="select COALESCE(ID, 0) from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"; 
$queryempt=mysql_query($empty)
if ($queryempt = 0){
 $lastrow = 1;
}
Else {
$lastrow="select ID from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"; 
$lastrow=mysql_query($lastrow);
echo $lastrow;
$lastrow=mysql_result($lastrow,0) + 1;
}

Comment: No you don't need to do this `if-else` your code is fine, just replace the query and you're good to go.

Comment: $lastrow="select COALESCE(ID, 0) from $sectionN order by ID desc limit 1"; 
$lastrow=mysql_query($lastrow);
echo $lastrow;
$lastrow=mysql_result($lastrow,0) + 1;                                     Still get the same error      Warning: mysql_result(): Unable to jump to row 0 on MySQL result index 9 in C:\wamp\

Answer (score 0):

Change your query and include a `WHERE` condition like

```
select ID from $sectionN 
where ID is not null
order by ID desc limit 1
```

Comment: I need to check with condition first if Id is null or not, so that if it is null return row 1